# Можно ли использовать data-атрибуты в реакт компонентах?

Tags: reactjs

У меня часто возникает ситуация когда в "верстку" нужно записать какое-нибудь значение, например айдишник чтобы потом его как-то использовать.
Использую для этого дата-атрибуты (data-cval={111}), потом например по клику получаю так **event.target.dataset.cval**. Есть предположение что делаю что-то неправильно, редактор ругается на синтаксис, говорит что такие атрибуты в jsx не поддерживаются. Код работает. Есть ли альтернатива?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так `data-cval={111}` все работает.

Comment: Вопрос в том есть ли альтернатива именно data-attrname, почему редакторы jsx ругаются на такую запись?

Comment: у вас объекты под руками а вы используетет дата атрибуты). Разве нельзя в onClick={this.clickHandler(id-чегото там)}